# making FSIN/FCOS results fit inside the unit circle

Tags: delphi, floating-point, delphi-2009, fpu, x87

In an ideal world for a given angle, the identity FSIN * FSIN + FCOS * FCOS = 1 would always hold true, however because of floating point limitations it isn't quite true. For example, passing a small value (like single 0x2F800001) to FCOS will give a result of 1 while FSIN will give a result greater then zero, therefore in this instance FSIN * FSIN + FCOS * FCOS > 1 .

In the current application I'm working on this is not acceptable, but what would be acceptable would be if FSIN * FSIN + FCOS * FCOS <= 1 . Sadly even in round towards zero FPU rounding mode, the above results still happen, so I need to do something about it.

I'm just wondering if anyone has a solution that's faster then redefining either FSIN or FCOS as follows since this solutions performance is rather low: FSIN = sqrt(1- FCOS * FCOS ) .

I'd prefer not using any external libraries to keep client happy, so would like a solution thats either assembler or delphi (client uses delphi 2009).

EDIT:

```
function test_asm2:single;
asm // math coprocessor set to no exceptions, 53 bits precision, and round towards zero
 mov word([esp-2]),$1E3F
 fldcw word([esp-2])

 mov dword([esp-4]),$2F800001

 fld dword([esp-4])
 fsin
 fmul st(0),st(0)

 fld dword([esp-4])
 fcos
 fmul st(0),st(0)

 faddp
end;
```

This works exactly like what I describe want to happen, FSIN * FSIN + FCOS * FCOS <= 1 with rounding flag set to trunc for all valid angles. Therefore it appears when I go back to work tomorrow I'll have to either trace to find where the client's compiler resets the rounding mode or make an assembler version of the calculation.

Comment: I am unable reproduce your issue. Your input data is IEEE-754 single precision. If I compute `FSIN * FSIN + FCOS * FCOS` with an argument of `2.32830671e-010  0x1.000002p-32  2f800001` and store the result to a single-precision variable, I get `1.00000000e+000  0x1.000000p+0  3f800000`. Stored in double precision, I get `1.0000000000000000e+000`. What is the context of your computation? Is it strictly necessary to compute the sine and cosine? Side remark: You may want to use `FSINCOS` to compute both trig functions at once and a bit faster than when using separate `FSIN`, `FCOS` instructions

Comment: Even the raw 80-bit result for your test vector comes out as 1 when stored with `FSTP TBYTE PTR[raw]`: `raw = 3fff_8000000000000000`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and interest njuffa. When I got home and saw your message, I retested this in pure assembler, and FSIN * FSIN + FCOS * FCOS seems to always be <=1 when the rounding mode is set to trunc. Therefore I strongly suspect that somewhere in the calculation the delphi 2009 compiler my client uses must reset the rounding mode to round rather then trunc. I'll update the main question with the assembler I just wrote if you want to look it over but it appears the actual solution will be to assemblerize the client's code to avoid compiler "optimizations".

Comment: The precision-control setting of the x87 FPU may also influence your results. For example, on my platform the default x87 precision control setting is double precision. Using an exhaustive test of all single precision arguments <= 2*PI, with the final result stored to a single-precision variable, detected no results > 1, using the default rounding mode of round-to-nearest-or-even. Same for the final result stored to a double-precision variable.

Comment: I just did the exact same test njuffa and can confirm your findings. I'm assuming it simply shuffles data between FPU registers and memory many times since this involves multiple roundings. For example, with angle $379837F4 and saving them to memory as singles before reloading for the next operation I'm able to reproduce the problem with round, but not with trunc. Therefore it appears this problem comes from the compiler forcing multiple consecutive roundings that throw some values off.

Comment: I'd suspect that the best solution involves lifting the unit circle limitation